# IsapiRewrite Lite + Wordpress - Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, iis, httpd.conf, isapi-rewrite

I am trying to get Permalinks to work on Wordpress on a IIS Server. I installed Isapi-Rewrite Lite and copied htaccess content into httpd.conf as follows :

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
LogLevel debug

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I try to access pages, it does work, but files can't be access (it's like if the RewriteCond where ignored). By instance, CSS, JS files don't work, even not the license.txt file : all I get is 404.

Here is the log output :

```
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (1) Htaccess process request C:\Program Files\Helicon\ISAPI_Rewrite3\httpd.conf
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (3) applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (3) applying pattern '.' to uri 'favicon.ico'
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='D:\MYPATH\favicon.ico' pattern='!!-f' => matched
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='D:\MYPATH\favicon.ico' pattern='!!-d' => matched
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (1) Rewrite URL to >> /index.php
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (2) rewrite 'favicon.ico' -> '/index.php'
132.203.118.127 132.203.118.127  Wed, 16-Apr-2014  09:30:21 GMT [MYWEBSITE/sid#913661937][rid#18687664/initial] (2) internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Any help would be much appreciated... I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're 2 possible issues:

a. This line looks suspicious "(4) RewriteCond: input='D:\MYPATH\favicon.ico' pattern='!!-f' => matched", since you specified "!-f". This may indicate that you played around and did the double registration (possible under IIS6 only). Or have something else installed from Helicon.

b. ISAPI_Rewrite may have issues with permissions. It does not allow ISAPI_Rewrite to see if the file is real or not(List Folder content permissions), so it redirects EVERYTHING. Try to follow this - http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/security.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I spoke with the person that manages the IIS server and he says that it is not a double registration neither the permission issue. Any other idea? Would it solve my problem to get the paid version? Thanks again, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a HeliconTech employee. It should be one of the two. However, there's always a room for smth else. No, it's not going to be fixed by paid version. Just send a ticket to HeliconTech's Support.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll do that and follow up here on the solution

Comment: I gave all permissions to ISAPI_Rewrite and now it's working!